# Does Nextjs static routes read by crawler

Tags: next.js, seo, google-crawlers

I have `reactjs/nextjs` project, and aware I can deploy project with `npm run build` and `npm run export`, for first one you need `nodejs` server, second one work with any server, right.. now I wondering if I export via `npm run export` and get static export from my project, does crawler read my routes (url) such `site.com/product` or `site.com/product/x` is it good for seo to use static version of nextjs? or I need to use `npm run build` to create dynamic version on a nodejs server?

I searched a lot, but I don't find any answer, my project use `api`.

Comment: You need to run `next build` for both static export and running a prod Next.js server. Both `next export` and `next start` are SEO friendly, Next.js pre-generates all pages on the server by default.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export):

> > next export allows you to export your Next.js application to static
> > HTML, which can be run standalone without the need of a Node.js
> > server. It is recommended to only use next export if you don't need
> > any of the unsupported features requiring a server.
>
> If you're looking to build a hybrid site where only some pages are
> prerendered to static HTML, Next.js already does that automatically.
> Learn more about Automatic Static Optimization and Incremental Static
> Regeneration.

You are in need of api functionalities which means that you cant use `npm run export` But as from the docs running it the default way using `npm run build` provides you a hybrid version where your static pages are prerendered which is good for SEO and provides you a super fast webpage and it still considers dynamic pages like `apis`.